# Reading a file in Python won't read the first line

Tags: python, list

I am reading a text file, separating the word and the number with the comma then adding them into separate lists however, the first name gets omitted. Here is my code.

```
for line in keywordFile:
     line = keywordFile.readline()
     keyword.append(line[0])
     keywordValue.append(line[1])
```

Comment: Files can be iterated in Python. `line` is the "line" in the file.

Comment: Also, you don't appear to be splitting the line on a comma at all. `line[0]` and `line[1]` are just the first and second characters, respectively, in `line`.

Answer (score 3):

You're jumping ahead with the first `readline()` and just use `line` defined in the `for` statement.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you `keywordFile` is a file object and since file objects are iterator (one shot iterables) after the first line that you loop over it you consume the first line.

```
for line in keywordFile:
          ^
```

And then you are using `readline` to read the next line which is extra here, so for getting ride of this problem you need to remove this part.

Also as a more pythonic way you can use a list comprehension to create the list of words by splitting the lines with comma.If you want to create a list of all words you can use a nested loop :

```
with open ('filename') as keywordFile :
    words = [w for line in keywordFile for w in line.split(',')]
```

But if you want to put the separated words of each line in a separate list you just need to use a one loop :

```
with open ('filename') as keywordFile :
    words = [line.split(',') for line in keywordFile]
```

Or as a better choice use `csv` module to open the file as a separated words.You can pass a delimiter argument to `csv.reader` function :

```
import csv

with open('file_name') as f:
  words=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
```

Here `words` is a iterator from tuples of separated words. And of you want to concatenate them you can sue [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) function.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
for line in keywordFile:
     tokens = line.split(',')
     keyword.append(tokens[0])
     keywordValue.append(tokens[1])
```